# Replace the complete filenames for files with their MD5 hash string of the content in bash

Tags: bash, shell, md5

**Problem:**

I have a bunch of files in a folder,i want to rename all of them to the md5 of the content of the file.

**What i tried:**

This is the command i tried.

```
for i in $(find /home/admin/test -type f);do mv $i $(md5sum $i|cut -d" " -f 1);done
```

But this is failing after sometime with the error and only some files are getting renamed leaving rest untouched.

```
mv: missing destination file operand after /home/admin/test/help.txt
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Is the implementation correct? Am i doing something wrong in the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make things simple by making use the glob patterns that the shell provides, instead of using external utilities like `find`. Also see [Why you don't read lines with "for"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Navigate inside the folder `/home/admin/test` and do the following which should be sufficient

```
for file in *; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    md5sum -- "$file" | { read sum _; mv "$file" "$sum"; }
done
```

Try using `echo` inplace of `mv` first to check once if they files are renamed as expected.

To go to sub-directories below, which I assume would also be your requirement, enable `globstar`, which is one of the extended globing options provided by the shell to go deeper

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*; do
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to recursively rename all files with their md5 hash, you could try this:

```
find /home/admin/test -type f -exec bash -c 'md5sum "$1" | while read s f; do mv "${f#*./}" "$(dirname ${f#*./})/$s"; done' _ {} \;
```

The hash and filename is given as argument into the `s` and `f` variables. The `${f#*./}` removes the prefix added by `md5sum` and `find` commands.

Note that if some file have exact same content, it will end up with only 1 file.